# Getting the private ip address of an Rook/Shiny page user

Tags: r, ip-address, ipv4, r-rook-package, shiny-server

I have created some web app using `Rook` which listen to my network ip (192.168.xx.xx) at port 8000. Everyone inside my office can connect to them just typing `http://192.168.xx.xx:8000/page_name` in the browser. I need to monitor these pages usage and wonder how I can get the network ip address of those connected to them.

I'm not experienced in web development and from the research done so far it seems that using client side code like `JavaScript` it's very difficult (almost impossible) to achieve that, (correct me if I'm wrong). So, my question is: is there any way of getting the network client ip using server side code inside an Rook application? (If needed I'd be willing to change the web server, any solution appreciated).

Thanks and sorry in advance should my question seem confusing... in particular I'm unsure if other tags are needed.

EDIT: I would also accept answers using something different than `Rook` (but still in `R`)

EDIT 2:
I have set Shiny Server following this [link](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Ubuntu-step-by-step-install-instructions). I'm at step of configuring the Server in order to get the `access_log` that, according to @Thell, contains the information I need. In The `shiny-server.conf` I have added the relative statement and now is:

```
run_as shiny;

server {
  listen 3838;

  location / {
    site_dir /var/shiny-server/www;
    log_dir /var/shiny-server/log;
    directory_index on;
  }

}

access_log /home/michelec/log.txt;
```

the last line should tell shiny to write the access_log into my home folder. Nothing happens however, the log remains blank. according to [here](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html), in the *Formats* section, I should receive one of these logs:

```
default ':remote-addr - - [:date] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] ":referrer" ":user-agent"'
short ':remote-addr - :method :url HTTP/:http-version :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'
tiny ':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'
dev concise output colored by response status for development use
```

depending if you leave the default format or you change it.

Comment: Can you make your code available? There's not a lot out there on Rook other than the basic documentation, so answering your question will probably require a little experimentation, which will likely require a reproducible example.

Comment: @SchaunW  thanks for replying. Sorry, I have no code yet for this task. I'm doing reasearch every day. As it is, the question would be answered even with just a (valid) input to start coding this.

Comment: I had a play with this today - it seemed that `ip()` should be what you're after, but I couldn't get any output from it

Comment: @alexwhan hi, thanks for that. In which package is `ip`?

Comment: In Rook - from the help (p12) "ip(): Returns the remote IP address as a character string." and (p13): `res$write(c(’ip: ’,req$ip(),’\n’))`. But I repeat - this did NOT work for me, otherwise I would post it as an answer. It only gave empty output.

Comment: @alexwhan Thanks a lot. I had a look at that. `req$ip` seems to be a call to `env[["REMOTE_ADDR"]]` which is `NULL`...

Comment: Deploy your Rook app with [rApache](http://rapache.net/manual.html#Rook) and you will end up with a nice `access.log` in standard format (with IP and time-stamp).

Comment: @daroczig thanks for your input. I'll install and configure rApache asap, probably on Friday and update with the code.

Comment: @alexwhan The source of rook shows the addr is written when rApache is the backend, so that command should work after setup.

Comment: @Thell my apps currently run on windows but I've a got a virtual machine with ubuntu server to test `rApache`. Regarding `Shiny`, would retrieve the local ip be possible with it?

Comment: @Thell I've managed to setting up the server. It's amazing! Thanks, probably I'm on the right way. But I'm a bit stuck in the 2nd step, (setting the config log). would you tell me how to do that? it'd be great!

Comment: @Thell I've edited the question with my attempt of setting the `config_log`

Comment: @Thell everything done! I have now a detailed report with all accesses. Thanks a lot. I'd be happy to accept your answer if you post it (bounty is about to expire..)

Comment: Michele, it may be worth while to alter the Question title and the tags used.  I'll clean up my comment steam and put it in an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Thell I know (I personally mentioned my doubts about tags when posted). I'll make a change, feel free to edit again if necessary. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Rook will only provide remote add when backed by rApache.

Another option would be to setup [shiny-server](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Ubuntu-step-by-step-install-instructions) from the fine folks @ RStudio and then [configure the access log](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/blob/master/config.html#access_log) such that you'd be able to parse that using the selected [access log format](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html) that you choose.

I'd lean toward the Shiny solution as the author of rApache also helped on Shiny and Shiny (being that it is an official product of RStudio) seems poised for growth and long term availability which we [can't really say about rApache](http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/37117851804/its-time-for-a-change-a-shiny-one) (as fine as it is!).

Comment: thanks for your patience during this week! By the way, in these days, while setting shiny up, I saw that it is build onto `Node.js`, which allows getting the ip very easily through the `connect` module. this module is the thing behind `access_log`, but unfortunately in shiny, differently then with Node, you can't access the retrieved ip into the server side code. According to this discussion [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/susan/shiny-discuss/EGQhEyoEk3E/lNQ5jLbPOBsJ] they are working on it

Comment: My pleasure.  Interesting...  I bet that could be inserted fairly easily into the api; and I'm guessing that those types of full control features will need to be in place for the enterprise edition, so be patient; or better yet, hack that shiny source! :)